# Loading .txt file into a 2D String Array

Tags: java, arrays, 2d, java.util.scanner, try-finally

I'm currently working on an assignment and have went through the workbook and java site multiple times and I can't seem to see where I got this wrong.

I am trying to import a file into a 2D Array. I am using Scanner w/ BufferedReader and FileReader to select a Command-Line argument (titanic.txt). I through in the //TEST if statement to see if it "fileInput" was still null. No issues while building, just while running.

Here is a portion of my code:

```
    //Declare Variables
    String[][] titanicArray = new String[1308][6];
    int[] classArray = new int[1308];
    int[] survivedIntArray = new int[1308];
    double[] ageArray = new double[1308];
    double[] ticketPriceArray = new double[1308];
    String inputFile = null;
    String answerStr = null;
    int answer1 = 0;

    Scanner fileInput = null;
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    inputFile = args[0];

    //try statement to scan command-line argument and fill the array with the data
    try {
        fileInput = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile)));
        //TEST
        if (fileInput != null){
            System.out.println("Error Taking in file");
        }

        for (int row = 0; row < titanicArray.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < titanicArray[row].length; col++){
                while (fileInput.hasNext()){
                    titanicArray[row][col] = fileInput.next();
                }
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (fileInput != null){
            System.out.println("Error Taking in file");
            fileInput.close();
        }//End of If for closing Scanner
    } //End of finally to close Scanner
```

NOTE: titanic.txt has data like below (Class, Suvived, Name, Sex, Age, TicketPrice) w/ tab and no blank-lines:

1   1   Allen, Miss. Elisabeth Walton   female  29  211.3375

1   1   Allison, Master. Hudson Trevor  male    0.9167  151.5500

1   0   Allison, Miss. Helen Loraine    female  2   151.5500

1   0   Allison, Mr. Hudson Joshua Creighton    male    30  151.5500

1   0   Allison, Mrs. Hudson J C (Bessie Waldo Daniels) female  25  151.5500

1   1   Anderson, Mr. Harry male    48  26.5500

1   1   Andrews, Miss. Kornelia Theodosia   female  63  77.9583

Comment: What "issues" are you having?

Comment: _This Code Does Not works_ , where is the issue precisely?

Answer (score 3):

```
   if (fileInput != null){
        System.out.println("Error Taking in file");
    }
```

There seems to be an ovious mistake in your code:
Why shoul `fileInput != null` be a problem?
Anyway, it is always a good idea to clean up and simplify code first, then ask for help. Some ideas:

- seperate file handling and file parsing into seperate methods
- use try-with-resource to simplify Exception handling and resource closing

Answer (score 0):

The size of array(columns) that you took is too small `.next()` gives you the first six strings only while the names in your input seem to be far too long.